# How to get vertical value in horizontal format in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned two table:

Table1:

```
ID          Date
X1          2019-01-01 14:12:18
X2          2019-01-01 18:43:32
```

Table2:

```
ID2       Variable_Name       Value
X1        state               NY
X1        Country             USA
X1        Pin Code            10001
X2        state               TX
X2        Country             USA
X3        Pin Code            73301
```

I need to fetch the details by joining both the tables in the following format:

```
ID          Date                 State        Country          Pincode
X1          2019-01-01 14:12:18  NY           USA              10001
x2          2019-01-01 18:43:32  TX           USA              73301
```

I am trying to use below query, but it didn't work fine.

```
select x2.ID,x1.Date,
if(x1.Variable='state',x1.value,null) as `State`,
if(x1.Variable='Country',x1.value,null) as `Country`,
if(x1.Variable='Pin Code',x1.value,null) as `PinCode`
from Table2 x1
           left join Table1 x2 on x2.ID=x1.ID
           where x2.ID in ('X1','X2') and x1.Variable_Name in 
                            ('state','Country','Pin Code')
                            GROUP BY x2.ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use conditional aggregation to get your desired results. Note that since the query has conditionals on `Variable_Name` in it, you don't need that to also be in the `WHERE`clause:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.Variable_Name = 'state' THEN t2.Value END) AS state,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.Variable_Name = 'Country' THEN t2.Value END) AS Country,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.Variable_Name = 'Pin Code' THEN t2.Value END) AS `Pin Code`
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID2 = t1.ID
WHERE t1.ID IN ('X1', 'X2')
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Date
```

Output:

```
ID  Date                state   Country Pin Code
X1  2019-01-01 14:12:18 NY      USA     10001
X2  2019-01-01 18:43:32 TX      USA     73301
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dXttsRnngdQxUToNuubQdt/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT for all if blocks

Example:

GROUP_CONCAT(if(x1.Variable='state',x1.value,null)) as `State`,

or if you can see full query it will be like this..

select x2.ID2,x1.Date,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(x2.Variable_Name='state',x2.Value,null)) as `State`,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(x2.Variable_Name='Country',x2.Value,null)) as `Country`,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(x2.Variable_Name='Pin Code',x2.Value,null)) as `PinCode`
from Table2 x2
LEFT JOIN table1 x1 on x2.ID2=x1.ID
GROUP BY x2.ID2;