# how to group data after doing a UNION ALL in laravel with eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I need to group data from two queries to the same table with two different conditions, for them I use UNIONALL() but it shows me an error.

my code

```
$query = DB::table($sub)
    ->select('categories.id as categoryID','categories.name As nombre_categoria','type'
    ,DB::raw('TRUNCATE( SUM( (points/'.$valor_poinst_value->puntos_por_dolar.') - ((points/'.$valor_poinst_value->puntos_por_dolar.')*'.$comision.') ),2) as total_sales'))
    ->join('consultancy_requests','session_id','=','consultancy_requests.consultancy_id')
    ->join('advisors','consultancy_requests.advisor_id','=','advisors.id')
    ->join('advisor_assignments','advisors.id','=','advisor_assignments.advisor_id')
    ->join('category_region','advisor_assignments.category_region_id','=','category_region.id')
    ->join('categories','category_region.category_id','categories.id')
    ->where('advisors.parent_id','!=',NULL)
    ->where('categories.parent_id','!=',NULL)
    ->groupBy('categories.id','categories.name','type','points');

    $f_chat = DB::table($query)
    ->select('categoryID','nombre_categoria',DB::raw('SUM(total_sales) as total_chat'))
    ->where('type','chat')
    ->groupBy('categoryID','nombre_categoria');

    $f_call = DB::table($query)
    ->select('categoryID','nombre_categoria',DB::raw('SUM(total_sales) as total_call'))
    ->where('type','call')
    ->groupBy('categoryID','nombre_categoria');

    $algo = $f_call->union($f_chat);
    $so = DB::table($algo)
    ->select('categoryID','nombre_categoria','total_call','total_chat')
    ->groupBy('categoryID','nombre_categoria')
    ->get();
```

error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;total_chat&#039;
 in &#039;field list&#039; (SQL: select `categoryID`, `nombre_categoria`, `total_call`, `total_chat` 
from ((select `categoryID`, `nombre_categoria`, SUM(total_sales) as total_call from (select `categories`.`id` as 
`categoryID`, `categories`.`name` as `nombre_categoria`, `type`, 
TRUNCATE( SUM( (points/20) - ((points/20)*0.1) ),2) as total_sales 
from ((select `session_id`, `spent_points` as `points`, `type` from
```

the result i hope to get

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what to answer but, maybe tracing the queries can help you.

1. try your expected query db first at database console. then execute.
2. then compare the expected query (number 1) to your query builder, by change `->get()` to `->toSql()`

`CASE WHEN` inside `SUM` could help you to get value by `type` without union.

```php
$so = DB::table($query)
            ->select(
                'categoryID','nombre_categoria',
                DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'chat' THEN total_sales END) as total_chat"),
                DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'call' THEN total_sales END) as total_call"),
            )
            ->groupBy('categoryID','nombre_categoria')
            ->get();
```

I got reference from this thread [How to get vertical value in horizontal format in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046210/how-to-get-vertical-value-in-horizontal-format-in-mysql)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).